# Empty array returned from ng-repeat in protractor test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have the following html

```
<div data-ng-controller="exampleCtrl as ec">
   <div data-ng-repeat="item in ec.items">
      <blockquote>
         {{item.name}}
      </blockquote>
   </div>
</div>
```

In my example.page.js file I attempt to get the list of item.name using

```
this.names= element.all(by.repeater('item in ec.items').column('item.name')).map(function (names) {
   return names.getText();
});
```

Then in my example.step.js file I do

```
examplePage.names.then(function (names) {
   console.log("Names length : " + names.length);
};
```

(Here examplePage is a new example.page.js)

Names has length 0 according to the log, though on screen there are 2 items visible each with names.

Also, if I just do `this.names = element.all(by.repeater('item in ec.items').column('item.name'))`, then I can see that names has length 2, but don't know how to get hold of the 'names' text. When I log them I just get [object Object], [object Object].

So it seems that calling the map function is somehow losing the 2 items.

Using the evaluate function as suggested I get items.length = 1, then if i do `console.log(items[0])` I get the whole element printed like

ElementFinder {
  ptor_: 
   Protractor {
   ......

I've tried doing `getText()` of this element, but get the same thing printed out.

Any suggestions why this might be? I have done very similar things recently and it has worked, but for some reason on this occasion it's not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `evaluate()` - It should evaluate the scope variables if `getText()` couldn't get the text

[Documentation on evaluate](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.evaluate)

```
this.names= element.all(by.repeater('item in ec.items')).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.evaluate('item.name');
});

names.then(function(allValues){
    console.log(allValues.length)
})
```

Comment: I've tried this and logged out allValues.length and allValues[0] and got 0 and undefined.

Comment: Oddly, I did `this.names = element.all(by.repeater('item in ec.items'))` then got that has length 2. I then did `var mappedNames = this.names.map...` with the evaluate function and mappedNames is of length 2, but mappedNames[0] is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Adityas's answer, Instead of using `map()` function, you can directly use `evaluate()`.

```
this.names= element.all(by.repeater('item in ec.items').evaluate('item.name').then(function(itemNameAsArray){
 console.log(itemNameAsArray.length)
})
```

Comment: As with my comment to Adityas's answer, this returned 0 and undefined